# visual studio 2012 shortcut to implement interface

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

It appears that Visual Studio 2012 has removed the automatic implementation of abstract classes that inherit from an interface, any idea how to fix this in 2012 version?

Comment: That gives me the abstract class methods which works fine but if that abstract class implements an interface I don’t get the interface properties.

abstract class MyAbstract : ImyInterface

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It seems to still be possible. Please see this [How To article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht46sc8e.aspx)

I tested it and it seems to work just fine.

[image: StringComparer]

[image: new implementation after clicking]

> Use this procedure to perform the Implement Abstract Base Class
>   IntelliSense operation. For more information, see Implement Abstract
>   Base Class. To implement an abstract base class using IntelliSense

1. Create a console application.
2. Place the cursor after the `class Program` statement.
3. Type `: StringComparer` so the class declaration becomes `class Program : StringComparer`.
4. Click the smart tag under `StringComparer`, and click Implement abstract class 'System.StringComparer'. IntelliSense adds three override methods from the `StringComparer` class to the `Program` class.

I created an interface `IModelBase`

```
namespace VendorPrototype.Model
{
    interface IModelBase
    {
        int ID();
        DateTime CreatedDate();
        String CreatedBy();
        DateTime LastModifiedDate();
        String LastModifiedBy();
    }
}
```

and a class `ModelBase`

```
abstract class ModelBase : IModelBase
{
}
```

When I clicked `IModelBase` and hovered under it, I was able to see the menu.

[image: Implement interface 'IModelBase']

Comment: CTRL+. will expand the smart tag for you as well.

Comment: I believe the default keyboard shortcut to expand the smart tag is ShIFT+ALT+F10. You can customize the keyboard to map it to a different shortcut. I use CTRL+ALT+<.> (Strangely, I tried mapping it to CTRL+<.>, but it didn't work.) -- (Where <.> is the period character).