# How to set Intellisense to add automatic methods to the top of a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

There is a visual studio shortcut to implement abstract methods as discussed here:
[visual studio 2012 shortcut to implement interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369048/visual-studio-2012-shortcut-to-implement-interface)

When I use the shortcut, these methods are added to the bottom of the file. How can I set this up to add them to the top of the file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I use the shortcut, these methods are added to the bottom of the
> file

It seems a bit more complex than that.

If you have a `class` with only `public` methods, it will add the new methods at the bottom.
If you have a `class` with only `private` methods it will add the new methods at the top.

Most likely what's happening is the Roslyn compiler is trying to place these `public` methods before any existing `private` ones, since its the compiler doing the work, I'm 99% sure there's no way to change this. To be 100% sure you'd want to look at the compiler source code:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn